# Drowdown list validation does not show error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 4 same dropdown list , user must at least select the first one. So I added a validation for the first one. If the value of the first dropdown list is 0 then show error message.

HTML:( the first dropdown list)

```
<select id="form22" class="select form22" name="m22">
<option selected="selected"    value="0"> Choose....</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_item_dropdown", function(value, element) {  
        return this.optional(element) || value == 0 ;   
         }, "Please select an item from the dropdown list.");

$().ready(function() {
    $("#response").validate({

    rules: {
                form22:{ 
                         check_item_dropdown: true
                       }
            },

    messages: {
                form22:{
                        check_item_dropdown: " Please select an item."
                        }
              }

            });

    });
```

I dont know why there is no error message if I selected "Choose...." . Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems here. One is that form22 is optional from the looks of the code you have posted. To fix this, add required : true in your validator setup like this:

```
form22:{ 
  check_item_dropdown: true,
  required:true
}
```

The other is that you are returning true from the method if the value is 0. You want it not to be 0, right? So your check should be value !== 0 not value == 0.

Comment: That will also work but it's always better to use !==, it does type checking as well as equality. It's a good habit to get into. Similarly use === instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id attribute `form22` , use name attribute `m22` in your validation script.

Hope this will work for you.

**Edited**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.addMethod("check_item_dropdown", function(value, element) {  
    if(value == 0 || value == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   
}, "Please select an item from the dropdown list.");

$().ready(function() {
    $("#response").validate({

        rules: {
            m22:{ 
                     check_item_dropdown: true
                   }
        },

        messages: {
            m22:{
                    check_item_dropdown: " Please select an item."
                    }
          }

    });
});
</script>
```

I have made some change in your `validator method` , `if` condition for check `value` is `0` or `blank`. And also set name attribute in validation , i have also tested in my localhost.

Also remove `selected="selected"` from option.

Its working now. try this and let me know if this work for you.

Comment: form22 is also a class on the select element so the validator will pick that up. That should not be the problem here. See the documentation at http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/ "There are several ways to specify validation rules.

    Validation methods without parameters can be specified as classes on the element (recommended)
    Validation methods with parameters can be specified as attributes (recommended)
    Both can be specified as metadata using the metadata plugin
    Both can be specified using the rules-option of the validate()-method"

Comment: @user2210819 Now try my edited code and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Choose option as like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose....</option>
```

Comment: How is that going to match value == 0 in the check_item_dropdown method?

Comment: It is not possible to have a value 0? Why I need to change that option ?

Answer (score 0):

your addmethod somewhere problem ...try this addmethod...

```
 $.validator.addMethod("check_item_dropdown",function(value, element, param)
    {
             var notDefault = true;
             if(element.selectedIndex == 0)
                      notDefault =false;
             return this.optional(element)|| notDefault;
    }, "Please select an item from the dropdown list.");

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#response").validate({

        rules: {
                    m22:{ 
                             check_item_dropdown: true
                        }
                }
         });

        });
```